# ASP.NET UserControls - how do I make a content field accessible from aspx code?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I can't find a good article that solves my following issue, so if anyone has the answer or just a link to the answer I would be happy.

Let's say I have created a UserControl called MyUserControl.ascx

I reg it in ascx with prefix uc

```
<uc:MyUserControl runat="server" id="uc_test" SomeProperty="true">
<InnerContent>
  ...
  Controls added in here....
  <asp:Button runat="server" id="btn_test" Text="Test">
  ...
<InnerContent>
</uc:MyUserControl>
```

I know how to create a usercontrol and how to add properties and events to it.

BUT how do I make the "InnerContent" field in my usercontrol?

I have no clue so please be a little specific :)

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually don't do that with user controls (`.ascx`). It's completely possible though. This is mostly done in custom controls you build using code files. To accomplish it, you declare your control class like:

```
[ParseChildren(true), PersistChildren(false)]
public class MyControl : Control, INamingContainer {

   [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
    TemplateContainer(InnerContentTemplate)]
   public ITemplate InnerContent { get; set; }

   void CreateChildControls() { 
       InnerContentTemplate temp = new InnerContentTemplate();
       InnerContent.InstantiateIn(temp);
       Controls.Add(temp);
   }
}

public class InnerContentTemplate : Control, INamingContainer {

}
```

For `.ascx` files you could inherit it from `UserControl` instead.

Templating in ASP.NET is a rather complex thing. It's not really possible to explain everything in an answer. You should look at some samples and documentation.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am trying to accomplish, but could you give an example of the setter function?

maybe loading the data into a Panel in the UserControl?

Comment: Thanks and I get what you are saying, will read up on it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is workign for me but I can't seem to find a way to get the controls I have added in the template back out again.
Have any quick hints for me on this one?

Comment: Tried `Control.FindControl` method?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a templated control, rather like a Repeater (ie, you have an ItemTemplate region, plus headers and wotnot). [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/TemplatedControl.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=910746&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick) is an example.

Comment: Thanks for this link, will try it out!

Answer (score 0):

In extension to the comments made to Merhdad's reply:
This is working for me but I can't seem to find a way to get the controls I have added in the template back out again. Have any quick hints for me on this one? – The real napster (14 mins ago)
Tried `Control.FindControl` method? – Mehrdad (8 mins ago)

..................

I can find the Template by accessing the panel I added it to.. Something like this:

```
pnl_content.Controls[index]
```

but I have no idea how to get the controls from the template..

This is what my code looks like:

```
<uc:PopupOKCancel ClientInstanceName="pop_createCompany" runat="server" ID="pop_createCompany" OKButtonText="opret" HeaderText="Opret nyt firma">
     <ContentTemplate>
           <uc:CompanyDetails runat="server" id="uc_companyDetails"></uc:CompanyDetails>
     </ContentTemplate>
</uc:PopupOKCancel>
```

The CompanyDetails UserControl doesn't seem to exists actually.. It seems that only the template exists.. I have tried adding some properties to the Template class so I could set them and get them but that was not possible.. for some reason.